# Qt: QAction doesn't appear in menu if the constructor string starts with the substring "about"

Tags: c++, qt, menu, qmenu, qmenubar

Are certain strings treated differently by the QAction constructor? This is very strange - if the QString in the constructor begins with "About" that seems to make the QAction invisible in the menu.

This snipped is within a method of a child class of QMainWindow:

```
mFileMenu = new QMenu(tr("&File"), mMenuBar);
mFileMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("Export &Data"), mFileMenu)); // appears
mFileMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("About"), mFileMenu)); // doesn't appear
mFileMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("Abouut"), mFileMenu)); // appears
mFileMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("Abouto"), mFileMenu)); // doesn't appear
mFileMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("_About"), mFileMenu)); // appears
menuBar()->addMenu(mFileMenu);
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Try to add new action with `mFileMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("About")));` instead.

Comment: there's no constructor with a string without a parent. However using 0 for the parent pointer results in the same behavior.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue neither with nor without parent. Please provide more details about the problem.

Comment: Please provide what qDebug() << tr("About") returns

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac there is a note on the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QMenuBar.html):

> Qt for Mac OS X also provides a menu bar merging feature to make
>   QMenuBar conform more closely to accepted Mac OS X menu bar layout.
>
> The merging functionality is based on string matching the title of a
>   QMenu entry. These strings are translated (using QObject::tr()) in the
>   "QMenuBar" context.
>
> If an entry is moved its slots will still fire as if it was in the
>   original place.
>
> The table below outlines the strings looked for and where the entry is
>   placed if matched:

[image: note]

So the action does not disappeared anyway, this was placed on the application menu as a you can see in the following example:

[image]